# Windows Form: change dataGridView's first cell origin?

Tags: c#, winforms, matrix, datagridview

Long story short, I have this dataGridView and I want the cell [0,0] to be the cell on the lower-left corner of the grid, not on the top-left of the grid like it does by default.

For example, visually, if i do something like:

```
dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "a";
```

[I get this (sorry not enough reputation to post pictures)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv4gD.jpg)

but I'd like "a" to appear, by doing the same instruction, at the blue highlighted slot, and by doing stuff like adding a row it would be added on the top of the grid.

Many thanks in advance and regards

Comment: Sounds like a not-very-well-thought-through idea. If you want to add at the front simply do an Insert !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create one class like this:

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public new DataGridViewCell this[int col, int invertRow]
    {
        get
        {
            int recordCount = this.RowCount - (this.AllowUserToAddRows ? 2 : 1);
            return this.Rows[recordCount - invertRow].Cells[col];
        }
        set
        {
            int recordCount = this.RowCount - (this.AllowUserToAddRows ? 2 : 1);
            this.Rows[recordCount - invertRow].Cells[col] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and call that like this:

```
dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "a";
```

or if you want set or get first cell in top-left of grid only then you can use [FirstDisplayedCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedcell(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

> MSDN: Gets or sets the first cell currently displayed in the DataGridView; typically, this cell is in the upper left corner.

For example:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.Value = "a";
```

Comment: Oh my god, excuse me i think he want to fetch any index ! i fixed as soon

Comment: I fixed by inverting row index.

Comment: Well, that won't really do what the OP wants. Quote: _by doing stuff like adding a row it would be added on the top of the grid._

Comment: I'll eventually work out on that, TaW. Still too bad that winform doesn't have this feature. By the way thanks, your method works well :D

Comment: Ah by the way (sorry for the double post) it's this.Rows[this.RowCount - invertRow - 1]. Otherwise it causes an ArgumentOutOfRangeException because we're out of index

Comment: @Asduffo please wait to check that as again

Comment: @Behzad Khosravifar now it adds the element on the penultimate row (EG: if i put [0,0] it puts the value where [0,1] it's supposed to be). Still subtract 1 seems to works perfectly so don't worry about :D

PS: about adding row: I didn't know that insert could be used in that manner (i always used it in another manner) so i didn't know that it was perfect for my problem (and due to that i never had it in theory)

Comment: thanks for your comments, you can edit my answer and change any things of that, but now I tested that on my computer and that work correctly!

Comment: Oh my god, now I know what happen ! want you add value to new row? because `row[ dgv.RowCount -1] = new row (not created)`

Answer (score 4):

There's no native way to do what you want without extending the class, but you can use extension methods that will invert the row index for you:

```
public static DataGridViewCell FromLowerLeft(this DataGridView dgv, int columnIndex, int invertedRowIndex)
{
    return dgv[columnIndex, dgv.RowCount - invertedRowIndex];
}
```

This can be used as

```
dataGridView.FromLowerLeft(0,0).Value = "a";
```